# linked comboboxes in html

Tags: php, javascript, html

Basically my webpage has two comboboxes. First combo box is populated with data comming from MySql. There is a button `Add` to the side of combo box and when user selectes a item in combo box 1 , clicks on the `Add` button, that item should get added to the second combo box that is in the same page. Can anyone please tell me how to do this in javascript? or anything?

By the way my web pages are PHP pages.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you implementing your comboboxes? (Or do you mean select elements (which generate either list boxes or drop down menus, but never the combination of a drop down menu and a text box that is known as a combobox)?

Comment: Given your description of the UI, you would probably be better off using a `<select multiple>` or a set of checkboxes. I would go with the latter as they present a more intuitive UI.

Comment: Thanks @David. Yes, I mean to use select multiple. The function given by @Atli  is what I require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey. You could use a Javascript function like this:

```
function moveSelectedOption() {
    // Fetch references to the <select> elements.
    var origin = document.getElementById('origin_select');
    var target = document.getElementById('target_select');

    // Fetch the selected option and clone it.
    var option = origin.options[origin.selectedIndex];
    var copy = option.cloneNode(true);

    // Add the clone to the target element.
    target.add(copy, null);
}
```

Then you just add a call to it to the button's `onclick` event.

```
<button onclick="moveSelectedOption()">Add</button>
```

If you want to move it rather than copy it, remove the `cloneNode` line and just `add` the original `option`.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.